# Connect to Internet with GSM: modem connected, no Internet

Tags: gsm, at-command

I am connecting to my USB modem on a COM port and sending him commands:

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
AT$QCPDPP=1,1,internet,internet
AT_OWANCALL=1,1,1
AT_OHCIP?
```

modem is answering and I can see that leda are lighting as where there is connection established. I took these command by sniffing communication between GlobeTrotter Connect and COM port. LEDS are the same in both situations. But in Control Panel connection named with GlobeTrotter HSxPA Network Interface #2 is offline (no connection). What am I doing wrong?

When I'm watching GlobeTrotter program and in the same moment watching commands there is no more commands sent. When I click Disconnect in appliaction (GlobeTrotter) in the same moment I see that status if Local Network is changed, but no command are sent. Maybe I should enable it in Windows in my program?

Thanks for any help

Comment: BTW, the syntax of AT$QCPDPP is in direct violation of V.250 (http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en), strings MUST be enclosed in double quotes. Such anomalies are always a worrying sign in my opinion, because it shows lack of decent AT command knowledge. Unclear if the strings are given wrongly because of misbehaviour in the GlobeTrotter Connect program, or if the command is actually specified to receive strings that way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for sure that the internet connection initiated as a Dial-Up Network (DUN) connection and not as an [USB ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB) connection? The reason I ask is because for DUN then all communication is done with AT commands and what you have captured should be enough to reproduce. If the connection is an ethernet connection the AT commands are more likely to be only for configuration.

Of the four commands listed, only the first is a standard [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) command. DUN with standard commands would typically have invoked AT+CGACT to activate the connection. Maybe the 
AT_OWANCALL command is similar, although that is just wild guessing from the name on my part. You should try to get some documentation for these proprietary commands.